# Have scale animation AFTER translate animation from last position

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to apply a translate animation to the view from bottom right to center THEN scale animation from where it finished translation. Once this is done, I want the view to come back to its original size and position. Any idea how to do that? Here is the code  I am using for animation

```
TranslateAnimation translateAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, midScreenX, 0, midScreenY);
        translateAnim.setDuration(2000);

        ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1, 4, 1, 4, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1f);
        scaleAnim.setDuration(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

use an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) to chain the animations and use [`setFillAfter(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter(boolean))

```
    TranslateAnimation translateAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, midScreenX, 0, midScreenY);
    translateAnim.setDuration(2000);
    // user setFillAfter to make sure that we scale from the last position it was animated to.
    translateAnim.setFillAfter(true);

    // make scaleAnim final so we can use it in the AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd method
    final ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1, 4, 1, 4, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1f);
    scaleAnim.setDuration(2000);
    scaleAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    translateAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // now that the first animation is done, start the second
            someViewObj.startAnimation(scaleAnim);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    // start first animation
    someViewObj.startAnimation(translateAnim);
```

Android Docs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter(boolean)

Comment: This is starting both animations at the same time. I want the second one to start AFTER the first one is finished

Comment: Sorry for the mix up, [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)  is what you are looking for. see the above edit

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But then what happens is it returns it to the orginal position and then scale it. As I said in the question, it has to scale from the last position it was animated to.  And setFillAfter is not doing the trick

Comment: ARghh... I better lern2read.   Check the edit for use of `setFillAfter(true)` to get this working as you intend

Comment: Thank you but it does not work :( . It will scale it from its original position  (I did say it in the previous comment but I tried it anyways again). I think because setfillafter does not really change the coordinates, it just change the look of it